# ThreadPool with list of classes and member function

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I have a function that I would like to make multiThreaded with pool.

```
def find(item):
    curve=Curve(item)
    return curve._find()
```

The multi-threaded version wouuld check if the input is a list:

```
def find(item):
    if type(item) == list:
    items=item
    pool = ThreadPool(len(items))
    curves = pool.map(Curve, moniker)
    pool.close()

    pool = ThreadPool(len(items))

    # now comes the tricky part:
    results = pool.map(???) # curves is a list of class 
                            # with each having _find as a function

    pool.close()
    return results

    else:
        curve=Curve(item)
        return curve._find()
```

How can I call pool.map with a list of classes as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i did understand, you just need to declare a function to map over the items of the list:

```
def find(item):
    def find_(item):
        curve=Curve(item)
        return curve._find()
    if type(item) == list:
        items=item

        pool = ThreadPool(len(items))

        # now comes the tricky part:
        results = pool.map(find_, items) # curves is a list of class 
                                          # with each having _find as a function

        pool.close()
        return results

    else:
        return find_(item)
```